# Is there any AWS EMR Describe Cluster API throttling limits, where can I see the metrics for it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, throttling

I am running multiple AWS EMR clusters for various Big Data Processing.

I want to monitor the **AWS EMR Describe Cluster API** Usage i.e. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeCluster.html

Anyone have done this before or is there any AWS docs/links where this API limits is described ?

Is this a hard limit ? or can we increase this limit ?

**Note** : We have already implemented the Back-off retry mechanism to avoid throttling.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see it is mentioned in AWS documents. At the end of the article, there's also a link that provides more information on how to request more quota. Have a look.

[Aws Documetation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/throttling.html)

Comment: Thanks it was helpful

Comment: The link you shared has limits only for EC2 not for EMR.